# Updating SharePoint Hubsite properties post creation C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, hub-site

I am trying to update properties of a hubsite after I create it.

Step 1: create the hubsite as a normal site

Step 2: register it as hubsite using
tenant.RegisterHubSiteWithCreationInformation()

Code :
var hubsiteCreationInfo = new HubSiteCreationInformation()
{
LogoUrl = "logoUrl",
EnablePermissionsSync = false,
Description = "description",
Title = "Sample Hub",
SiteUrl = "ContextUrl"
};
tenant.RegisterHubSiteWithCreationInformation(hubsiteCreationInfo.SiteUrl, hubsiteCreationInfo);
await adminCsomRoot.ExecuteQueryAsync();

Error/exception: The list item could not be added or updated because duplicate values were found in the following field(s) in the list: [HubSite, Site].

Do we have a way of creating and THEN updating properties of a Hubsite. or we only can create it along with the properties provided? Namewise RegisterHubSiteWithCreationInformation seems like a method we should be able to use after creation; similar to RegisterHubSite(which works fine in the above case)

Answer (score 0):

This method is used to create a new site as a hub site. For existing one you should use `RegisterHubSite(url)` method.

Use this link for the reference (line 640): [ObjectHierarchySequenceSites.cs](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/Framework/Provisioning/ObjectHandlers/ObjectHierarchySequenceSites.cs)